# Difference between openfire users and roster Users

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I have gone through many documentation but still I am not able to clarify the difference between user created in openfire and that in roster. I simply need to get all user list from openfire in my android application so that I can do one to one chat with other users. Also please explain difference between Roster user and Simple user.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are an User when you register yourself and you'll choose user and password.

If you get as example Skype (it's not Jabber as I know), when you register yourself with an email to Skype service you'll be an User.

Roster it's the equivalent of Skype's CONTACT LIST.
In XMPP you can meet and talk with any user if they are in a groupchat, while you can chat 1-1 only with people of your Roster.

It's possible to skip the Roster by configurations, groupchat or simply developing a shared all-inclusive Roster as your needs.

In Roster you can assign a nickname to your contact (your contact it's an User) that can be different between Rosters because it's a kind of personal configuration.

Roster can handle groups (family - frinds - clan...), can handle personal users Message of the Day ("hello world") or simply status (offline - online - away - busy...).

Roster handles Presence stanzas.

I suggest to setup the chat with a standard behaviour so in future will be easy to upgrade server and client or extend functionalities.

Comment: @MrPk- I only want one to one chat as of now. Is it possible through Roster or through OpenFire Server Users..

Comment: Roster it's on client side, Users are on server side. All users can see other users in server and ad-hoc functions (like search one) but XMPP protocol adds the Roster to avoid to be contacted by anyone who only wants to spam. So there exist also configurations to allow this usage and skip the Roster. Don't think what you "need" but focus how the protocol/specifications can handle your needs ;)

Comment: BTW, Roster are stored also on database (so you can access it server side) but it's a funcionality that mainly you "use" on client